# SSH Function Error in ZSH

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh

I have the following function in my `zshrc` file:

```
fssh() {
    ssh -NfL $1:localhost:$1 graphite
}
```

When I call `fssh 8443`, I get

```
Bad local forwarding specification '8443ocalhost:8443'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you get?

Comment: Updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zsh` is trying to interpret `:` as a special character after your variable.  Specifically it is trying to make it lower case.  In `zsh` `:l` and `:u` are used to get lower case or upper case versions of your varialble. So your function specifies to make `$1` lowercase with `$1:l`.

Properly defining the boundary of your parameter expansion should fix the problem, so try `${1}:localhost:${1}`

Good luck.

Comment: You're welcome. Happy scripting!